# Wireguard transfer of external ip address

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, openvpn, wireguard

There is an external server (host) with wireguard, ip address 98.XX.XX.XX and internal server (client) with wireguard 192.168.0.2.

On client installed web server (nginx, phpfpm). On host all ports forwarded to the client. If I get 98.XX.XX.XX im response web server page from 192.168.0.2. This is all fine, but on the client side in log file all connecrions has ip adress 192.168.0.1 (gateway wiregusrd host 98.XX.XX.XX).

I tried to do it with client side rules:

```
Table = 1
PostUp = ip rule add pref 500 from 192.168.0.2 lookup 1
PostDown = ip rule del pref 500
```

Server side rules

```
Address = 195.168.0.1/24
SaveConfig = true
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 98.XX.XX.XX -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443,25,53,21,20,110,113,465,587,993,995,4747,3306,4200 -j DNAT --to-destination 195.168.0.2
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 98.XX.XX.XX -p tcp -m multiport --dports 5432,43,143,123,8002 -j DNAT --to-destination 195.168.0.2
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -d 98.XX.XX.XX -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443,25,53,21,20,110,113,465,587,993,995,4747,3306,4200 -j DNAT --to-destination 195.168.0.2
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -d 98.XX.XX.XX -p tcp -m multiport --dports 5432,43,143,123,8002 -j DNAT --to-destination 195.168.0.2
ListenPort = 51823
PrivateKey =
[Peer]
PublicKey = 
AllowedIPs = 195.168.0.0/24
```

But, if i ping or send packeges from client 192.168.0.2 i have external ip my provider ip adress 169.XX.XX.XX. I need packets to be sent from the ip address 98.XX.XX.XX (host) wireguard

Simple scheme what i need

Client ip 24.18.22.12 -> Wireguard host (98.XX.XX.XX) -> Internal web server (192.168.0.2) (Internal web server seen client ip original 24.18.22.12, no wireguard gateway)

And if i post data from Internal web server (192.168.0.2) to google or some site, i get Wireguard host (98.XX.XX.XX) ip address, but not the provider ip adress 169.XX.XX.XX

Internal web server (192.168.0.2) -> google.com (google seen Wireguard host (98.XX.XX.XX))

Simple what i need:
In web server behind nat (wireguard) all http GET ips get ip address wireguard getaway (192.168.0.2) not 24.18.22.12 (real client ip)
192.168.0.2 - - `[08/May/2022:14:15:14 +0300] "GET /view.php?show=body HTTP/1.0" 200 2803 "https://site.domain/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36"`
All request, get, post and etc. has ip 192.168.0.2.

[image: What i need]

Comment: I want all traffic to go through wireguard and I can see the ip address of all requests in wireguard client

Comment: I delete cross-post. First time post and i dont know where i get answer. I update my question.

Comment: The question is correct, thanks to everyone for the help, how to find a solution I will write myself. I'm tired of explaining the same thing 100 times.

Comment: I already wrote the text and attached the picture, and you answer me some kind of nonsense.

Comment: A.B Goodbuy. Go spam to another place

Answer (score 0):

> Client ip 24.18.22.12 -> Wireguard host (98.XX.XX.XX) -> Internal web server (192.168.0.2) (Internal web server seen client ip original 24.18.22.12, no wireguard gateway)

Well, you're doing NAT, and that literally says the network address is *translated*. So, what you want is impossible.

So, you can't do NAT and not do NAT at the same time.

Wireguard is a Layer 3 tunnel, meaning you can actually only forward packets that are IP (v4, or v6), and if you want the client to handle packets for the host IP address, then you need to either run the HTTP server on the host, or use NAT (which you don't want). *I don't see a different way, unless you can expose a separate public IP address for the client.*

So, instead, you need to do the HTTP handling on the host (98.x.x.x); remove all the NAT rules you set up, set up an nginx as *reverse proxy*, that could potentially also handle the TLS connections and drastically reduce connection times, and talks to the actual web server over the wireguard tunnel using the internal (i.e., wireguard) client IP address.

> Internal web server (192.168.0.2) -> google.com (google seen Wireguard host (98.XX.XX.XX))

That's possible; your host can also play the role of a NAT'ing "VPN egress" for the client's outgoing connections if you will. I'd actually, for simplicity, and thus for cleaner configuration, and thus for higher security, just set up a separate wireguard tunnel for that, though, so that then your machines have the following setup:

[image: schema]

Comment: @A.B you might have lost me there, maybe because the original question uses the word "client" very ambigously. So, NAT in which direction (better: for which packets going in which direction), done where? If it's only done in one direction, how would the requests to google appear to come from the NAT'ing host, although the actual request was made by the machine with no public IP address?

Comment: @A.B ah, an understandable understanding of what OP might want! yeah, then that's easy enough, I'll still let my answer stand here as alternative proposal, because putting a reverse proxy on the actually exposed host makes sense (less roundtrip time for TCP link establishment from the actual internet-originating use, thus lower TLS connection establishment time, no NAT where no NAT is necessary (TLS stripping has to be done *somewhere*, anyways), second wireguard interface is cheap and allows for separation of concerns, especially if OP wants to add more services, failover/load balancing)

Comment: Thanq for reply. Sorry meybe my english not wery well but i ask how i can transmitted ip address client external (internet) to internal 192.168.0.2 (client). Gateway in server with wireguard.

Internet client ip 45.X.X.X -> wireguard host 98.XX.XX.XX -> internal 192.168.0.2 (wireguard client) in 192.168.0.2 i need see 45.X.X.X

Comment: Easy but how?)))) help pleace))

Answer (score 0):

**Hello , this is actually pretty easy !**

This is the "best" way to do it in my opinion instead of using proxy to add headers... This Policy method will work with everything not just web servers.

I'am using this to host Mail Server with correct Original IP for Fail2ban and other IP Related whitelisting. (Because my ISP block port 25)

**--- Hypothetical Network Layout ---**
| Location | Public IP    | Wireguard IP|
| --- | --- | --- |
| VPS | 46.123.123.0 | 10.0.0.1 |
| Home Server | 91.123.123.0 | 10.0.0.200 |
|[RGO] Random Guy Online | 64.123.123.0 |  |

**The objective here is to let RGO reach our Web page hosted on Home Server when using the VPS IP, but have the Original Source IP (RGO) reported for our services to use.**

**--- Steps ---**

First we need to add a DNAT Rule to route traffic to our Home Server (On the VPS)

Something like this would work for a simple setup:

```bash
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.200:80
```

**Basically we are asking the iptables to catch packets received with port 80 and overriding the default routing process to our own**

Now packets Flow in one direction but responses will not be routed correctly so instead of doing SNAT to get the packets flowing back we will use Policy Routing to get packets routed correctly when Home Server want to send data.

Its basically tagging the packets and Overriding the default routing to use our Wireguard Tunnel again.

So to achive this you should add this to your Wireguard Client (Home Server) config file:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <Wireguard Private Key HERE>
Address = 10.0.0.200
Table = 123

PreUp = ip rule add from 10.0.0.200 table 123 priority 456
PostDown = ip rule del from 10.0.0.200 table 123 priority 456

[Peer]
PublicKey = <Wireguard Peer PubKey HERE>
Endpoint = 46.123.123.0:51822
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0 # This is required for this method to work
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

**-- RESULT --**

Now your services at Home Server will see RGO IP when he request something to the VPS IP that have a DNAT Rule for it.

Have a nice day,
Hope this helps you even if i'am a year late :D

**Rayen Ben Ammar**